# How to stop my cloth simulation from bouncing like a piece of rubber

Tags: cloth-simulation

I looked into the two most recent questions with similar problems, but neither of them had an proper answer, here is my simulation. I applied smooth shading and solidify, has subdivision but not applied, all the other settings regarding collision and cloth simulation are shown in the video along side with the bake. I tried increasing the quality of both the cloth and collision, but would prefer a method which doesn't involve increasing too much of them again due to CPU capacity. I have no idea how to make the cloth do a free fall onto the objects, and then just fall off as normal cloth without bouncing around, please enlighten me, thank you very much!
[the video](https://streamable.com/lfp6du)

and the blend file
[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: yes! thank you for the link, the file has been edited to my post. I have edited it again after I posted the question, I've lowered the weight of the cloth and tweaked some other properties, but the problem remains

Comment: yes I don't know why the cloth keeps shivering, I hope someone will understand. By the way, I'm not sure why you've give a Collision to your cloth?

Comment: You can switch the cloth caching off at a certain frame in it's cloth-cache frame range.  That would certainly stop the bouncing but obviously the settings would need to reduce the bounce as much as possible beforehand.

Comment: @moonboots I planned to create two pieces of clothes and they will be colliding.

Comment: @Edgel3D yeah but that will not make the cloth fall off like a real piece of cloth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing is that you have the **Speed multiplier** in 6 meaning that your cloth simulation is progressing "times 6" you also need to take care of other setting but that will depend on the effect that you want.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/cloth/introduction.html

Hope that helps